# Is there a way to extract a type's keys at compile time?

Tags: typescript

I was wondering if it was possible do something like this:

```js
type FooBar = {
    foo: number,
    bar: number
}

const obj = {
    foo: 3,
    bar: 2
}

const keys = KeysOf<FooBar>() // keys = ["foo", "bar"]
function isFooBar(obj: any): boolean {
    for(key of keys) {
        if (!(key in obj)) {
            return false 
        }
    }
}
```

I know that types in TypeScript are a development concept, but it could be possible to implement this by making the TypeScript compiler extract those keys.

Comment: As written what you want is impossible.  That will compile to `const keys = KeysOf();` and so you'd be calling a zero-arg function named `KeysOf()`  and hoping it will magically know what type's keys you want.  If you want an array at runtime you will have to make it yourself, like `const keys: Array<keyof FooBar> = ["foo", "bar"]`.

Comment: Probably a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566/get-keys-of-a-typescript-interface-as-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it that way around, because TypeScript type information isn't available at runtime. You have to have a runtime array, `["foo", "bar"]`, in order to implement your type predicate. But that would *seem* to mean having the names in two places, which is a maintenance concern.

When I'm in this situation, I usually turn it on its head and create the runtime array, then define both the type and the type predicate in terms of the array, like this:

```typescript
const fooBarKeys = ["foo", "bar"] as const;

type TypeHelper<Keys extends PropertyKey> = {
    [Key in Keys]: number;
};

type FooBar = TypeHelper<typeof fooBarKeys[number]>;
//   ^? type FooBar = { foo: number; bar: number; }

function isFooBar(obj: any): obj is FooBar {
    for (const key of fooBarKeys) {
        if (typeof obj[key] !== "number") {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Example use of the type predicate:

```
console.log(isFooBar({foo: 42, bar: 67}));  // true
console.log(isFooBar({foo: 42}));           // false
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAhAhgJwNIFMCeEYC8MA2gEQIikA0MpARuqQLowr6iRQDcAUD1DgAOWGABUhWABJYANsLQAebHhhYAHlCxgAJvgAKaEPIHKAfIRgBvHjFsllMAJZgYyiEwBcMMAFcAtnRYaLwAvrz8EjAAYoioaBbiwtJyQQoCwiBw8LHobsS+AUFMprwA9KV2AHoA-HxwPmDAUI7gThAxyOgAFCB0AFZeKGA4AJRevX1t0Tnx1nbZ8V0c0DAA1rgwmdmdmLgQI1Y283aOWV3pWFsTxOs4LACEBESkBYFopAdzx99oWFA+aBccBQMggWF431sISOUJhMF+-0BMCgaB84J40J4yxAMiwADoZCAAOZdRztGZdSwULwAFgATDQGGgvAA2ADsIRGIy4tnKyNRWCx4AgOPxhJJZI6cUp1Jg9M53Mh8z5wNBgqAA)

You can also do it by using a "model object," which is just a different approach to the same concept of building the type information from data structures that are also available at runtime:

```typescript
const fooBarModel = {
    foo: 42,
    bar: 67,
};

type FooBar = typeof fooBarModel;
//   ^? type FooBar = { foo: number; bar: number; }

const fooBarKeys = Object.keys(fooBarModel) as Array<keyof FooBar>;

function isFooBar(obj: any): obj is FooBar {
    for (const key of fooBarKeys) {
        if (typeof obj[key] !== typeof fooBarModel[key]) { // This is imperfect, but better than nothing
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(isFooBar({foo: 42, bar: 67}));  // true
console.log(isFooBar({foo: 42}));           // false
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAhAhgJwLIgCYFMA2MAvDAN4BQMV8iAXDACwBMANJdQEbr0BsA7GwC+AbnLkoATwAOuGADFEqNMRiSZIODWTosefKID0B6gD0A-GNCRYCbWgDSuCRBUB5DgCtcwKADoA1k4QABS2SroEAJQwKC4AgmhoKBIAPIESGvKK6AB8ouRwAK5gPgCW4DClEAp2wSCe9ChgEpH09R6VLjVKZOxUCMrBVtAw6TCZYeiOztEU1POVmsFquJntANrpALowAIREJCsT2Zg4BJtOW7MwRjAAKgAWVZ2VALYyaHDeUCwwHIWwDi4KBQXDKKAPJowMAgCGlMAAcz6C3maGBhTQYHgKHwEFwohRVEEyOJqPRmNUaEK+PIxPIwxA+FwvnwIARwSq3XQwVItnozF+XDQvD4gkikWEVFuUCpuHp4AgjOZrPZnJOPL5jCYYolhPmtzgOLx5CAA)